# Stationary Distribution of a Random Walk

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, network

Consider the discrete time simple random walk $X_t$ on a finite connected graph with transition matrix $P$. At each step the walk moves to a neighbor uniformly at random. Assume that $X_t$ has a unique stationary distribution $\pi$ with mixing time $t_{\text {mix}}$.

let's fix $\alpha \in(0,1)$ and a vertex $v \in V$ (set of vertices) and define a new Markov Chain $\boldsymbol{Y}=\left(Y_t\right)_{t \geqslant 0}$, where at each step with probability $1-\alpha$ the walk moves to a neighbor uniformly at random and with probability $\alpha$ it moves to vertex $v$.

1. I want to show $\boldsymbol{Y}$ has a unique stationary distribution $\pi_v=\left(\pi_v(x)\right)_{x \in V}$ and its form.

Let's consider a sequence of graphs ($G_n$) with size of the vertex set. Also, assume that $\alpha=\alpha_n$ depends on $n$. If $t_{\text {mix }}(n) \cdot \alpha_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$,

2. Does the stationary distributions also converge to that of its limit?
   $$ \max _{v \in V_n} d_{\mathrm{TV}}\left(\pi_v, \pi\right) \rightarrow 0 \text { as } n \rightarrow \infty .
   $$

Answer (score 0):

Showing that there is a stationary distribution in 1 is easy: the graph is undirected and connected, so it's irreducible, and there's a self-loop from $v$ to itself, so it's aperiodic, so there is a unique stationary distribution that is approached in the limit.

In terms of showing what its form is, I don't really see how that's possible at this level of generality. It is not just a trivial modification of the original stationary distribution. For example, notice that if you have *any* regular graph, the stationary distribution of the random walk on the graph is uniform, but now as you move $v$ around a regular graph you will see stationary distributions that are biased in favor of $v$ and nodes not too far from $v$.

2 seems plausible intuitively but I don't see how you'd set up a proof for it analytically.